# One result for datalist item

Tags: html, css, mysql

I have a database with a large numbe of records. I want to show the records as autocomplete in datalist. Is there some  way to show only the first option in autocomplete though it should contain all the records. I just want to show one, i.e., the first result of datalist.
Thank You

Comment: Do you have any code yet? If not, then try to program it yourself and if / when you encounter problems, ask about them here. Stack Overflow is more focused on solving specific problems than programming something from scratch. Thanks!

Comment: not yet understand your mean. but if you want to show only one record just use "LIMIT numberOfRow;" see more informations at: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp for mysql